# Did anybody write when-let-cond?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I was thinking about a cond with a twist

```
(let ((a 0))
  (let* ((result nil))
    (tagbody
       (let ((b1 (+ 0 a)))
         (when (eq b1 1)
           (print "1")
           (setf result b1)
           (go finish)))
       (let ((b2 (+ 0 a)))
         (when (eq b2 2)
           (print "2")
           (setf result b2)
           (go finish)))
       (when T
         (print "else")
         (setf result a))
       (format t "=== ~A~%" a)
     finish)
    result))
```

where `when` test-form is wrapped in `let`. On one hand this seems to fit into a problem I am working on, but also seems overcomplicated. Can it be simplified with a macro? What would be the best way to simplify it if I had lots of test-forms?

Part of the problem in trying to do it that way is restricting the let blocks to only one test-form and its body.

But I wonder if I am going down the wrong path. Playing with an imaginary variant of when-let suggests there is no benefit of going down this path.

## Trying cond

The version using cond appears to be more compact.

```
(let ((a 3))
  (let* ((b1 (+ 0 a))
         (b2 (+ 0 a)))
    (cond
      ((eq b1 1)
       (print "1")
       b1)
      ((eq b2 2)
       (print "2")
       b2)
      (T (print "else")
         a))))
```

All boils down to the variables defined in the let* which in real life example would be used to avoid calculating the same value twice and improve readability. What should I do?

Comment: when_let is a popular macro that happens to be defined in the Alexandria library (and probably a lot of other ones). https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/

Comment: Does when-let set the returned result and then jump to the finish of tagbody? Sounds like you are suggesting to write my own version of when-let.

Comment: numbers need to be compared with EQL or =. EQ does not compare numbers by value, but by object identity.

Comment: Or use a pattern matching library like trivia/optima.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd prefer to think more in terms of blocks and returning values from them, instead working with goto and variables. If one really needs separate let-bound variables and their own scope:

```
(prog ((a 0))
  (let ((b1 (+ 0 a)))
    (when (eql b1 1)
      (print "1")
      (return b1)))
  (let ((b2 (+ 0 a)))
    (when (eql b2 2)
      (print "2")
      (return b2)))
  (return
    (progn
      (print "else")
      (return a))))
```

Comment: Your answer is much better than my suggestion for using macrolet. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody did now.  I wanted it to be compatible with `cond` which raises a trouble: if you want the binding clauses to be like

```
(cond/binding
  ...
  ((var expr) <use var>)
  ...)
```

But you want to allow just general test clauses, then a function with one argument is ambiguous:  should

```
(cond/binding
  ...
  ((car x) ...)
  ...)
```

call `car` or bind `car`?  To make this work then you need to bind a useless variable in that case:

```
(cond/binding
  ...
  ((useless (car x)) <useless not used here>)
  ...)
```

And that means you either need to insert `ignore` or `ignorable` declarations all over the place, or live with compiler warnings.

So, well, I decided it would be better to go the other way: you have to *say* when you want to bind a variable.  And you do that by a clause like:

```
(cond/binding
  ...
  ((bind var expr) <var is bound here>)
  ...)
```

And note that `bind` is magic in the syntax (so this means you can't call a function called `bind`, but that's OK as I already use `bind` as a keyword in [other macros](https://github.com/tfeb/tfeb-lisp-hax/blob/main/README.md#local-bindings-binding).

The macro also tries hard (well, hard given I basically just typed it in and it's had no testing) to actually behave like `cond`: returning multiple values, for instance.

So this:

```
(cond/binding
  ((f x y z) t)
  ((bind x 3) (print x) (values x t))
  (t (values nil nil))
  (1))
```

expands to

```
(block #:cond/binding
  (when (f x y z)
    (return-from #:cond/binding (progn t)))
  (let ((x 3))
    (when x
      (return-from #:cond/binding
        (progn (print x) (values x t)))))
  (when t
    (return-from #:cond/binding (progn (values nil nil))))
  (let ((r 1))
    (when r
      (return-from #:cond/binding r))))
```

(where all the blocks are the same block).

So, here:

```
(defmacro cond/binding (&body clauses)
  ;; Like COND but it can bind variables.  All clauses are (should be)
  ;; like COND, except that a clause of the form ((bind var <expr>)
  ;; ...) will bind a variable.  Note that bind has to be literally
  ;; the symbol BIND: it's magic in the syntax.
  (let ((bn (make-symbol "COND/BINDING")))
    `(block ,bn
       ,@(mapcar
          (lambda (clause)
            (unless (consp clause)
              (error "bad clause ~S" clause))
                (case (length clause)
                  (1
                   `(let ((r ,(car clause)))
                      (when r (return-from ,bn r))))
                  (otherwise
                   (destructuring-bind (test/binding &body forms) clause
                     (typecase test/binding
                       (cons
                        (case (car test/binding)
                          ((bind)
                           (unless (and (= (length test/binding) 3)
                                        (symbolp (second test/binding)))
                             (error "bad binding clause ~S" test/binding))
                           (destructuring-bind (var expr) (rest test/binding)
                             `(let ((,var ,expr))
                                (when ,var
                                  (return-from ,bn
                                    (progn ,@forms))))))
                          (otherwise
                           `(when ,test/binding
                              (return-from ,bn
                                (progn ,@forms))))))
                       (t
                        `(when ,test/binding
                           (return-from ,bn
                             (progn ,@forms)))))))))
          clauses))))
```

Caveat emptor.

Comment: Ouch! SO should have an option for honourable mention. I have googled for caveat emptor and I get your point. I did not think of the need to return multiple values. I was just experimenting with going off the beaten track and playing with different possibilities of parsing and traversing some unusual data structures.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you problem correctly, then you can use `or` and rely on the fact that `when` is evaluated to `nil` if the condition is not true, e.g.,

```lisp
(defun example (a)
  (or
   (let ((b1 (+ 0 a)))
     (when (eql b1 1)
       (print "1")
       b1))
   (let ((b2 (+ 0 a)))
     (when (eql b2 2)
       (print "2")
       b2))
   (progn
     (print "else")
     a)))
```

Comment: " (that is, the body of a let is an implicit progn)." so says Hyperspec for Special Operator LET, LET*. for some reason that I forgot now, I had a problem with the "else" part, so I went looking in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

Using macrolet is the best solution so far. That allows me to bypass the limitations of when-let and not all bindins in the let form have to evaluate to true.

```
(let ((a 3))
  (let ((result nil))
    (macrolet ((ret-go (res)
                 `(progn
                    (setf result ,res)
                    (go finish))))
      (tagbody
         (let ((b1 (+ 0 a)))
           (when (eq b1 1)
             (print "1")
             (ret-go b1)))
         (let ((b2 (+ 0 a)))
           (when (eq b2 2)
             (print "2")
             (ret-go b2)))
         (when T
           (print "else")
           (setf result a))
         (format t "=== ~A~%" a)
       finish)
      result)))
```